# Does the new Orchard Core have a Shape Tracing Tool/Module?

Tags: orchardcore

I noticed the Original Orchard CMS has a module for Shape Tracing within the browser, it looked awesome.

So I was wondering if there was any equivalent in Orchard Core?

thx.

Comment: Or anyway of finding out what shapes are being rendered ?

Answer (score 1):

Orchard Core also has Shape Tracing Tool, but it does not available under stable RC2 build. To use this tool you have to switch to "nightly" build. Detailed instructions how to enable Shape Tracing Tool in your project you can find at [Orchard Dojo](https://orcharddojo.net/blog/shape-tracing-helpful-extensions-alt-and-class-attributes-for-the-image-shortcode-this-week-in-orchard-28-08-2020)